# Better to migrate before upgrade to Lion, or upgrade before migrating?

Tags: upgrade

I'm getting a new MacBook Pro, and I am wondering about the relative merits of:

- installing Mountain Lion on the new laptop before migrating my account from my old MBP; or
- migrating my account and then upgrading to Mountain Lion

Or are the two methods functionally equivalent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is best to upgrade and then migrate. Usually problems occur while upgrading, and it is best to upgrade or install from scratch, as opposed to upgrade on a system which might have something incompatible already installed.